# heroku and github - started with heroku and now want to move into github

Tags: git, heroku, github

Ok, so I am new to heroku and github.
I used Heroku to deploy my node.js app.
As I undersdtand now, Heroku has a github by default, and I want to start having my own private repo.

I created a new git repo (my own private one) and now I want to :
1. Hook my local project to my own git repo - so how do I "delete"?? the git connection of Heroku?
2. After I will have my project statt using my own repo, I would still like to deploy via Heruko.

any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

> I want to hook my local project to my own git repo - so do I
>   delete Heroku connection ?

No, you don't need to.

You just need to add your bitbucket repo as a remote with a name say 'bitbucket' and use that name to push to bitbucket when you want to

```
git remote add bitbucket https://bitbucket.org/username/reponame

git push bitbucket branch_name
```

> After I have my project in my own repo, I would still like to deploy
>   via Heruko.

Sure, you can continue to use both Heroku and bitbucket at the same time and when it comes to pushing your code you use the desired remote repo.

Comment: Thanks, but I am not sure I understand what to do. This is my git remote -v status:
heroku  https://git.heroku.com/SOMETHING.git (fetch)
heroku  https://git.heroku.com/SOMETHING.git (push)
origin  https://github.com/<my-user>/SOMETHING_ELSE.git (fetch)
origin  https://github.com/<my-user>/SOMETHING_ELSE.git (push)

So, now, what is the proper procedure to update ALL repo's (mine and heruko) and deploy on Heruko?
Should it be the simple usual 3 lines:
git add .
git commit -m "update"
git push

And that's it? the add/commit/push will be reflected on both repo's?

Comment: your local repo is just one and there can be multiple remote repos(viz. heroku, origin, bitbucket) linked to this one local repo. So you add your files and commit them as you do in git but when it comes to push you choose where to push changes i.e. git push origin or git push origin heroku or git push bitbucket and accordingly the remote repo gets updated with the local repo changes.

Comment: if you want to update all the remote repos using just one command then you can set multiple push url with the same remote:                                           git remote set-url origin --push --add <a remote>
git remote set-url origin --push --add <another remote>